# How to return a string in json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have am using ajax to retun a array [[int,string],....] in index.json.

Here is my index.json

```
<%= @custom_fields.map {|e| [e.id ,e.name] }.to_json%>
```

and that is my ajax requiest

```
 $.get("/categories/" + (categoryId) + "/custom_fields.json", {}, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      });
```

console.log prints nothing.

It work almost fine, cause in server log( when i use raise ....inspect) I have

```
("[[17,\"\\u0411\\u0440\\u0435\\u043d\\u0434\\u044b\"]]")
```

It have normal id , but my string value "name" is encoded(I think so).
What I am doing wrong. String is in Russian language, maybe cause of this I have that problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: you should check firebug or similar tool of other browsers... are they showing right results?

Comment: i am using chrome tool. It have same result

Comment: The string is just encoding up the UNICODE charaters, thats the way JSon encodes strings, i cant see anything wrong in the JSON

Comment: but it doesnt work... in browser same result as server log haves

Comment: Can you try with a ascii string? It shouldn't matter but just to be sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saying you have json in `index.json` and in `$.get` request you have specified `custom_fields.json`. Is this correct?

There are few steps to debug this type of issue.

- If you are using Firefox browser you can use Firebug to monitor the
  XHR calls.
- If you are using Chrome you can use its built in developer tool to
  monitor the XHR calls.
- You can determine whether the call is being made. If yes then what is
  the raw response from the XHR call.